# Подмена контекста данных и тестирование

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, юнит-тесты

Добрый день! У меня есть веб-приложение asp.net mvc. Для работы с базой данных я использую класс репозитория, который общается с бд через Entity Framework. Я решил написать юнит-тесты на класс Repository и для этого вместо использования конкретного класса контекста данных с помощью Dependency Injection внедрил интерфейс. Было так:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext 
{
    DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }    
}

public class Repository 
{
    private MyContext _context;

    public Repository() 
    {
        _context = new MyContext();
    }

    public Foo GetFoo(int id)
    {
        return _context.Foo.Find(id);
    }
}
```

Стало так:

```
public interface IMyContext 
{
    DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext: DbContext, IMyContext 
{
    DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }    
}

public class Repository 
{
    private IMyContext _context;

    public Repository(IMyContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Foo GetFoo(int id)
    {
        return _context.Foo.Find(id);
    }
}
```

Вроде бы всё прекрасно - репозиторий больше ничего не знает о конкретной реализации контекста, и ему можно подсунуть фейковый конекст в целях тестирования. Но не всё так просто. Как можно видеть, сам интерфейс "знает" о таких сущностях, как `DbSet<T>` и прочих подробностях EntityFramework, которые в приведённом коде для краткости были опущены. То есть к проекту, содержащему юнит-тесты, надо будет подключать пакет EntityFramework. 
Насколько это вообще правильно? Или репозиторий нужно тестировать как-то иначе?

Comment: Обычно в таких тестах подменяют сам репозиторий, а не контекст. Но есть решения и через подмену базы данных (см. пакет Effort)

Comment: @PavelMayorov просто в репозитории есть какая-никакая логика. Разве её не целесообразно тоже протестировать?

Comment: Логику, лежащую в репозитории, тестировать можно только на тестовой БД, на то он и репозиторий.

Comment: Модульные тесты тут бесполезны хотя бы потому что они не покажут оптимальность планов запросов.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал заглянуть сюда: [Proper way to Mock repository objects for unit tests using Moq and Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2102104/5275890)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ок, чтобы избежать очередного ответа не в тему "а вы сделайте интерфейс IRepository", попробую расписать суть коммента Mayorov-а:

Репозиторий (в том смысле, который обычно вкладывается в этот паттерн в приложениях с EF внутри) - это сборник запросов. Вы:

- Объявляете интефейс IRepository, с кучей методов типа `FindBy`
- Не возвращаете из этих методов родной `IQueryable`, всегда делаете в реализации этих методов `ToList()` / `First()` / и пр. - всегда материализуете результат запроса

Весь код, который использует репозиторий, вы тестируете юнит-тестами подменой реализации на тестовый репозиторий.

Сам репозиторий вы тестируете интеграционными тестами, с живой базой и реальным EF.

Тестировать репозиторий юнит-тестами можно, но очень тяжело и достаточно бессмысленно. Что может пойти не так и что могут выявить тесты:

- Код построения запроса написан совсем криво. Строит не то, передает параметры не туда. Ок, это еще можно проверить юнит-тестами, разобрав дерево выражений. Жутко трудоемко. Но легко проверяется интеграционными тестами.
- Код построения запроса написан нормально, но генерирует что-то, что EF не может выполнить. Гораздо более вероятно, нельзя проверить юнит-тестами, легко проверяется интеграционными тестами.
- Проблемы с производительностью написанных запросов. Вообще нельзя поймать юнит-тестами, можно поймать интеграционными тестами + ручным анализом медленных тестов.

Вам стоит или писать на репозиторий интеграционные тесты с реальной базой, или не писать их вовсе.

Answer (score -1):

Не связывайте интерфейс с `DbContext`-ом. Используйте универсальный интерфейс:

```
public interface IRepositoryEntity
{
    T Get<T>(int id);

    IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>();
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);

    T Create<T>(T newObject);

    T Update<T>(T obj);

    bool Delete(int id);
    bool Delete<T>(T obj);
}
```

И реализацию для `EntityFramework`:

```
public class EFRepository : IRepositoryEntity
{
    private DbContext _dbContext;

    public T Get<T>(int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
    }

    // И так далее
}
```

Потом всё делается просто. Для теста регистрируете `EFRepository` по интерфейсу `IRepositoryEntity`. Таким образом вы отвяжитесь от надобности добавлять ссылки на `EntityFramework`

Comment: Топикастер пытается писать тесты на репозиторий. Писать тесты на TestRepository несколько бессмысленно, а как именно тестировать EFRepository ваш ответ не говорит.

Comment: @PashaPash. Да, я не так понял, но это не отменяет того что я написал в начале ответа. Если следовать этой логике, то к тестам не надо будет подключать `EntityFramework`

Comment: да, но ваш ответ все еще не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. Т.е. на какой-то вопрос он отвечает. Но не на тот, что задал топикастер.

Comment: и да, вы же знаете разницу между `Func<T, bool> filter` и `Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter`? Представляете как поведет себя EF на таблице в 1M строк, если вы сделаете `_dbContext.Where(filter)`  в вашей реализации?

Comment: @PashaPash, ок, тут спорить нечего, вернее использовать `Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter` разницу я себе представляю.

Comment: Тогда получается, что юнит тесты не дают никакой гарантии на нормальную работу полноценного приложения - т.к. фильтры собираются у вас в коде, вызывающем репозиторий, но реально не проверяются и не отрабатывают. Т.е. весь код, занимающийся построением условий для выборки данных, покрыт не будет.

Answer (score -1):

Вы пытаетесь включить в тест не только логику своего приложения но и тестирования стороннего сервиса (EF).
Реализация интерфеса от @Chloroform правильная. Интерес должен быть абстрагирован от всего. А вот реализации сервиса может использовать что угодно. Хоть ADO, хоть EF.

Единственный, с моего опыта, подходящий вариант - использовать Mock/Microsoft Fakes framework

Первый идет как плагин и не имеет всех реализаций, как Fakes. Но если у вас не корпоративная лицензия другого выхода нет.

Теория с примерами по Mock 
https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/18.5.php

Fakes
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh549175.aspx

Это будет легкий способ переопределись возвращаемые значения из неконтролируемых методов.

Comment: Нет, топикастер не пытается включить в тест логику стороннего сервиса. Вы невнимательно прочитали вопрос. Он использует паттерн репозиторий в смысле "сборник запросов". И он хочет тестировать локализованные в репозитории запросы. А "реализация" репозитория Chloroform вообще ужасна - она принимает на вход "Func<T, bool> filter", что (сюрприз-сюрприз!) вытянет в базу содержимое всей таблицы на любом запросе.

Comment: На всякий случай - суть вопроса - топикастер не хочет тестировать сервисы и BL с привязанным EF. Он хочет протестировать запросы, локализованные в репозитории. Есть более-менее стандартный подход - не выдавать из репозитория IQueryable, локализовать сборку запросов в репозитории. Писать на весь остальной код юнит-тесты (не боясь, что код соберет невыполняемый запрос), писать на репозиторий интеграционные (чтобы проверить, что написанные в нем запросы выполняемы через EF). Топикастер спрашивает, как писать юнит-тесты на репозиторий. Ему в комментах ответили, что никак.

Comment: Вот именно их можно переопределись для возврата "нужного ответа". (наполнить файковый набор данных из БД) 
return _context.Foo.Find(id); и DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }  и есть попытка протестировать то, что делать не следует.

Comment: Ок, давайте я переформулирую его вопрос - у него есть оторванный от кода репозиторий, в котором собраны запросы. Это позволяет подменять реализацию репозитория на тестовый при тестировании, например, сервисов. Это все ок, и топикастер спрашивает не про это. Но при этом в репозитории есть код построения запросов (хотя бы `_context.Foo.Find(id)`, и более сложный для более сложных запросов). Как тестировать этот код в репозитории?

Comment: Ответ "не тестируйте код построения запросов вообще", очевидно, так себе. Запросы бывают сложные, и написать что-то, что EF не проглотит - проще простого. Написать что-то, что EF сделает дико неэффективно (как в ответе Chloroform) - еще проще.

Comment: Ок. спасибо за пояснение.